# Display Background Color through Transparent Background Image

Tags: css, html, background, background-image, background-color

I have an `div` element in the web page and I'm going to set both background color and background image for it. The image has a transparent background, and I want the background  color to be shown under the image. Is it possible?

Answer (score 16):

Yeah you only need to have an image with a transparent background and after that you use this

```
body {background:#ffffff url('img_tree.png') no-repeat right top;}
```

the `#ffffff` is the color that you want behind your image.

Very important that your image extension support transparency, use .png or .gif